# Hierarchical select population jQuery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I have 3 select boxes in HTML, see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VJtYg/).

What should happen: when one clicks on one of the options in the first `<select>`, data should be loaded into the second `<select>` from a database. When one clicks on data in the second `<select>`, the third `<select>` should be populated with further data from a database.

**Simple question**

What is the best and easiest way to store and load the data in a hierarchical fashion. Like a [tree view](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/Generic_Tree_View/GenericTreeView.JPG) but with `<select>` elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BqvrJ/1/ - is a start to see how you can use jquery to load the data. I've just used dummy arrays though.

Answer (score 2):

Use ajax and you can either us append to your select the php of options.

```
$.post('thephp.php',{parameter,value},function(data) {
    $('selectid').append(data);
}
```

Or you can use json and add that way.